# matplotlib scatter plot legend not dependent on the colour of the point

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I want to make my legend to the scatter plot not dependent on the colour of the point. The simple example is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fake_data = np.array([[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]])
fake_df = pd.DataFrame(fake_data, columns=['X', 'Y'])
groups = np.array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
fake_df['Group'] = groups
names = np.array(['bla', 'blu', 'ble', 'blam', 'blom', 'bluh', 'bom', 'bam', 'bem'])
fake_df['names'] = names

group_codes = {k:idx for idx, k in enumerate(fake_df.Group.unique())}
fake_df['colors'] = fake_df['Group'].apply(lambda x: group_codes[x])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
scatter = ax.scatter(fake_data[:,0], fake_data[:,1], c=fake_df['colors'])
for num, names in enumerate(fake_data):
    plt.text(fake_data[num,0], fake_data[num, 1], num)
handles = scatter.legend_elements(num=[0,1,2,3])[0] 
ax.legend(title='Group\nCodes', handles=handles,  labels=group_codes.keys(), bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

I want to save the colours, because I have cluster analysis there, but I want to have a legend that will look like that:

```
1 - 'bla'
2 - 'blu'
3 - 'ble' and so on.
```

Current plot:

[image: current plot]
The dataframe looks like:

```
   X  Y Group names  colors
0  1  1     A   bla       0
1  1  2     A   blu       0
2  1  3     A   ble       0
3  2  1     B  blam       1
4  2  2     B  blom       1
5  2  3     B  bluh       1
6  3  1     C   bom       2
7  3  2     C   bam       2
8  3  3     C   bem       2
```

I have only made a not very useful numerating of the points, but I would like to connect numbers with the corresponding names, which would be shown in the legend.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Congratulations with supplying fully reproducible test code. Could you clarify your ¨"and so on"¨? Do you need the "Y" column as number together with the "names" column? So, nine entries in total for the legend?  Do you want to ignore the colors in the legend?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough, I would like to have nine entries in the legend total and legend looking like: 1 - 'bla', 2- 'blu', 3- 'ble', 4- 'blam', 5- 'blom', '6- bluh', 7- 'bom', 8 - 'bam', 9- 'bem'. Colours may remain, but the point is that I want to connect point on the plot with its number and then connect number with its name, so the colour of the point in the legend is not so important - I can look at my legend and see what colour the point has

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, u need  legend with entries like 1 - 'bla', 2 - 'blu', 3 - 'ble', and so on, connecting the numbers to the corresponding names, right

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fake_data = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]])
fake_df = pd.DataFrame(fake_data, columns=['X', 'Y'])
groups = np.array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
fake_df['Group'] = groups
names = np.array(['bla', 'blu', 'ble', 'blam', 'blom', 'bluh', 'bom', 'bam', 'bem'])
fake_df['names'] = names

group_codes = {k: idx for idx, k in enumerate(fake_df.Group.unique())}
fake_df['colors'] = fake_df['Group'].apply(lambda x: group_codes[x])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
scatter = ax.scatter(fake_data[:, 0], fake_data[:, 1], c=fake_df['colors'])
for num, name in enumerate(names):
    plt.text(fake_data[num, 0], fake_data[num, 1], num)

handles = scatter.legend_elements(num=[0, 1, 2, 3])[0]
labels = [f"{num} - '{name}'" for num, name in enumerate(names)]
ax.legend(title='Legend', handles=handles, labels=labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `scatter.legend_elements(num=fake_df['colors'].tolist())` you can get a legend handle with the correct color for each row in the dataframe. Enumerating through the names, you can create a new list with strings which combine the numbers and the names.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fake_data = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]])
fake_df = pd.DataFrame(fake_data, columns=['X', 'Y'])
groups = np.array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
fake_df['Group'] = groups
names = np.array(['bla', 'blu', 'ble', 'blam', 'blom', 'bluh', 'bom', 'bam', 'bem'])
fake_df['names'] = names

group_codes = {k: idx for idx, k in enumerate(fake_df.Group.unique())}
fake_df['colors'] = fake_df['Group'].apply(lambda x: group_codes[x])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
scatter = ax.scatter(fake_df['X'], fake_df['Y'], c=fake_df['colors'])
for num, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(fake_df['X'], fake_df['Y'])):
    ax.text(x, y, f' {num + 1}')
handles = scatter.legend_elements(num=fake_df['colors'].tolist())[0]
labels = [f'{num + 1}: {name}' for num, name in enumerate(fake_df['names'])]
ax.legend(title='Group\nCodes', handles=handles, labels=labels,
          bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.01), loc="upper left")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: legend combining colors, numbers and names]